# Tire slowly deflates. One click per rotation noise while braking on same tire

Tags: brakes, tires, noise

2006 Buick Lucerne

I have to inflate my one driver's side rear tire about once week. 
This has been going on for nearly a year where I'll fill it to about 42 PSI and it'll deflate to about 25 PSI very slowly. I do not believe it's a slow leak as it seems to happen faster the more I use the car (which I know may make sense to a point).

My curiosity is if it could be related to a faulty tire/brake job, as I recall it started shortly after I had the car in the shop. Every time I break, I hear a click noise from what I believe is that same tire. I'd say it's one click per tire rotation. I'm wondering if the breaks are somehow squeezing the tire? The click happens at all PSI levels for the tire.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**I don't see how they could be associated**

Your tire is mounted to your rim.  The rim is mounted to the wheel hub.  Your break disc would be, in many cases, mounted by tightening the lug bolts to your rim.  The rim would press against the disc to tighten it your hub.

The clicking sound you are hearing could be related to the work you had done but would not be related to the slow deflation of your tire.  The brakes do not interact directly with the tire in any way.

**Deflation**

The deflation of your tire could be discovered through visual inspection.  Check all the tread and sidewall area for screws, nails, etc that may have penetrated the tire.  Additionally, you could use a bucket of soapy water and a rag after inflating and apply the soapy water everywhere to check for air bubbles from a leak.  Check the following.

- Tire bead - along the edge of the tire where it meets the rim.
- Valve stem - You may have a faulty valve stem where it meets the rim OR the schraeder valve inside the valve stem.  Take the cap off the stem and see if it's leaking there with your soapy water.
- All over the tire - Slop the soapy water all over the tread and sidewalls to see if you can find he bubbles

**Clicking sound**

There could be numerous reasons for the clicking sound.  If you have a speedometer cable (unlikely), all the way to some brush caught up in your wheel.  You may want to jack up that tire and spin it to see if you can discover the location.

Answer (score 4):

Most common cause of slow leaks is a foreign object has pierced and is lodged in the tire. I've had a nail twice, short screws 3 or 4 times. Look carefully all over the tread and in the grooves. Soapy water helps, but I've never needed it. Metal screws in rubber tires are always easy to find, just take a quick look every time you park the car. At some point, it will be on the top side of the tire.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how the deflation can be related to the brake job.  The click could be the sound of whatever it is that punctured the tire when It touches the pavement, or it could be unrelated.  If you don't have have a puncture it could be a bad tire valve core which is pretty easy to change yourself.  Soapy water will often show where the air is leaking.